# Why does my synchronous job code does not work

Tags: python, multithreading

I have wrote below code segment to initiate function in every 2 seconds. But, it seems it is not work. Why?

```
from threading import Timer

class A :
    value = None
    def AX(self):
        value = 12
        obj = B()
        Timer(1,obj.BY, [self.value]).start()
class B:
    def BY(self,value):
        print "refreshed :", value

if __name__=='__main__':
    obj = A()
    obj.AX()
```

Comment: You need to be clearer in your problem descriptions. What does 'seems not to work' mean? Do you get errors or is all that happens is that `refreshed' is not printed?

Comment: @MartijnPieters refreshed message does not emitted on the screen. I am so sorry

Comment: @MartijnPieters have you see the error ?

Comment: I see the `refreshed` message when I run the code, but with a `None` value. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to *set* `value` on `self`, or use the local variable as the argument:

```
def AX(self):
    self.value = 12
    obj = B()
    Timer(1, obj.BY, [self.value]).start()
```

or:

```
def AX(self):
    value = 12
    obj = B()
    Timer(1, obj.BY, [value]).start()
```

This prints:

```
>>> A().AX()
>>> refreshed : 12
```

Note that the `Timer()` instance will only call `obj.BY` *once*, it doesn't repeatedly call the function.

You need to reset the timer every time `BY` is called to do that:

```
class B:
    def BY(self,value):
        print "refreshed :", value
        Timer(2, self.BY, [value]).start()
```

which will create a loop. If you need that loop to terminate at some point, you'll need to test for that condition separately, in `BY`:

```
class B:
    somecondition = False

    def BY(self,value):
        print "refreshed :", value
        if self.somecondition:
            return  # do not set the timer again
        Timer(2, self.BY, [value]).start()
```

Comment: so sorry, I have wrote urgently. So I have editted my mistake, please look at. Thanks for your help

Comment: what should I do so that it will call obj.BY repeatedly?

Comment: @demilg: Create a new timer every time `BY` is called.

Comment: where should I create ? is in the BY method ?

Comment: And, If I wrote it in BY method, how can I stop the infinite loop?

Comment: Interestingly infinite loop, I got.

Comment: @demilg: Yes, restart the timer from the `BY` method; you need to determine for yourself when not to restart the timer again, in `BY` itself.